# Type Error on Transpiling Babel class.default is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

```
'use strict';
/**
* PortalHTML.js
*/

import SingleContextHTML from './SingleContextHTML';
import MultiContextHTML from './MultiContextHTML';

export default class PortalHTML{
    constructor (type) {
          switch(type) {
        case "1":
          this.portalStrategy = new SingleContextHTML();
          break;
        default:
          this.portalStrategy = new MultiContextHTML();
          break;
           }
    }

    render (...args) {
        this.portalStrategy.renderHTML(args);
    }

    _strategyPeak(){
        return this.portalStrategy.constructor.name;
    }
}

/**
* SingleContextHTML.js
*/
'use strict';

import PortalHTMLStrategy from './PortalHTMLStrategy';

export default class SingleContextHTML extends PortalHTMLStrategy {
    constructor(){
            super()
    }
    renderHTML(args){}
}

/**
* Multi.js (same as single) ^^ above
*/

/**
* PortalHTMLStrategy.js
*/
'use strict';

export default class PortalHTMLStrategy{
    constructor(){}

    renderHTML(args){}
}

/**
* Tester Mocha and Chai
*/

'use strict';

import PortalHTML from "./PortalHTML";
import chai from 'chai';

let basicPortalHTMLTest = () => {
    let singleContextHTML = new PortalHTML("1");
    let multiContextHTML = new PortalHTML("multi");
    describe('PortalHTML: Initialization of PortalHTML', () => {
        it('Should be an instance of class SingleContextHTML', (done) => {
            chai.expect(singleContextHTML._strategyPeak()).to.equal('SingleContextHTML');
            done();
        });

        it('Should be an instance of MultiContextHTML', (done) => {
            chai.expect(singleContextHTML._strategyPeak()).to.equal('MultiContextHTML');
            done();
        });
    });
};

basicPortalHTMLTest();
```

I am trying to test an implementation of a strategy pattern, but I am running into an error that states the following after I run my test script with mocha.

```
var singleContextHTML = new _PortalHTML2.default("1");
                                      ^                               
TypeError: _PortalHTML2.default is not a constructor
```

I am using node6 and the following babel packages:

```
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.11.0"
```

I have been trying to debug this for around half a day. If anyone sees anything immediately wrong that I am doing I would be **extremely** grateful.

Comment: `import PortalHTML from "PortalHTML";` appears to contain the wrong module identifier.

Comment: did you mean `from "./ProtalHTML"` ?

Comment: Yeah for this toy example, in my actual code the directory structure is correct. I updated to prevent confusion. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incorrect babel preset. Switching over to es2016 or above fixed this error.